# Using move with find from terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, find

This should be fairly straightforward, but I can't seem to get it. Little context, I got files let's say `test1.txt...test5.txt` distributed over several directories. I just want to find them, and move them to one directory.

I can use `xargs` with `find` but I want to use the `-exec` option in `find`. In which all the found files will be passed in one *"instance"* of `mv` command (correct me if I'm wrong), so here's the command:

`find . -name 'text*.txt' -exec mv '{}' collectedDir;`

I get this error: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`. I clearly am using a semicolon. So what could be the issue causing this?

Before you ask, `find` did find all the files, I used `print` to check, and `collectedDir` does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is seeing that `;` before `find` does and swallowing it.

You need to escape it `\;` so the shell doesn't eat it.

That said `-exec .. \;` will run the command once *for each file found* not once total.

To run it once for as many files as possible you need `-exec ... +`.

```
find . -name 'text*.txt' -exec mv '{}' collectedDir +
```

Comment: I did think of that, and escaped it. I got the same error.

Comment: When you have it unescaped the shell sees it even attached to the `collectedDir` word. When you escape it it becomes *part* of the word and you have a final argument to `mv` of `collectedDir;`. You need to add a space `collectedDir \;`.

Comment: Ah, I feel silly now. Thanks for the pointing it out, and telling the difference between `+` and `;`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in @EtanReisner post, you forgot to escape the semicolon, if you don't the shell interpret it as a commands separator; try with:

```
find . -name 'text*.txt' -exec mv '{}' collectedDir \;
```

You could also use `find` in conjunction with `xargs` to avoid calling the `mv` command for every file (which could be faster if you have a lot of files), like:

```
find . -name 'text*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t collectedDir
```

The `-0` flag "escape" all special characters which could be in the file names (like spaces or semicolons again).

Comment: Explaining why that first `find` command works when his original didn't would improve this answer.

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner, thank's for your comment, I'll keep it in mind next time :$

Comment: `-0` doesn't "escape" anything. `-print0` prints filenames delimited with NUL bytes (which aren't legal in shell variables and filenames) and `-0` (to `xargs`) tells it to expect NUL-delimited input.

Comment: This is why i said it will "escape" the names; by escaping i meant "that all characters which could have been interpreted are taken literally" (as written in the man).

Comment: Yes but that's not escaping. Escaping means to "escape" them which isn't happening. And no, if it were possible to get a NUL into the input stream some other way then `-print0 | -0` *wouldn't* be safe because the input stream values would *not* be escaped. It just isn't possible to do that.